# How is Female circumcision done?

Tags: fiqh, women, sunnah

السلام عليكم
Since the strongest position regarding female circumcision is that it is wajib, how is it done? What part of the females organ is cut according to the fuqaha? Is it the labia minora or the clitoral hood or both the clitoral hood and labia minora or the clitoris